# <authorization> can protect pages?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, authorization

Can I use `<authorization>` to protect webforms from being accessed if a person does not have a specific role?

I tried this:

```
<authentication mode="windows" />

<authorization>
  <allow roles="Admin" />
  <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

but if the role Admin is not available then I can still visit the page by typing in the URL. How can I protect this page?

I read the documentation on MSDN ([ASP.NET Authorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.aspx)).
I also put the `UrlAuthorizeModule` extra in the `web.config` to make sure that it gets hit.

Comment: I added that just before the end of the root tag in the web.config.

Answer (score 2):

Best to read this: [ASP.NET Authorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.aspx)

It explains how to set the allow/deny elements for users and roles.

Comment: This is not the solution. I've gone through the documentation, used it but it didn't provide the solution for me.